# iOS - NSURLConnection segfaults

Tags: iphone, ios, nsurlconnection

I'm trying to find why my app is crashing on an iPad 1 and not a iPad 2 or the New iPad.  When I'm trying to download stuff using NSURLConnection, I get:

```
 Job appears to have crashed: Segmentation fault: 11
```

The app crashes with nothing else logged to give me any hints of where to look.

I checked around and I do not have any diagnostic parameters in my app like NSZombies.  I am Profiling the Release version with Allocations in Instruments. Any thoughts?

Comment: are you getting memory warnings? might be that you are loading the data you are getting into memory, and the iPad 1 has significantly less memory than the iPad 2 and 3

Comment: Add a NSLog in "- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data" and log the amount of TOTAL memory you have accumulated up to that point (that is, the size of the mutableData object both before and after you add the new chunk to it) - you may find its huge. There is a function on SO that lets you log the total amount of memory your app is using at any one time.